# timeout and performance issues on redirecting inside django

Tags: python, django, redirect, timeout

I am currently having problems with Timeouts and performance on Django redirection. The issue was not visible until I was surfing to my locally hosted application with 2 devices and only one worker enabled on my localhost, timeout set to 30 seconds.

I have a views.py function that redirects a page, based on  that is given the URL. I do a lookup for the pk in a table and return the url. I also have a counter that keeps track of the amount of forwards.

urls.py here:

```
url(r'^i/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', frontendapp_views.item_view, name="item_view"),
```

The page redirects instantly to the "desired_url_forward", however, the connection stays open with the user, while in fact, the user has left my Django environment. This somehow leaves my worker waiting for 30 seconds while I was already forwarded to an external page, not allowing to process any other request with one worker.

I could increase the number of workers or shorten the timeout time, but that doesn't feel right as it is not fixing the core issue.

This is the only thing I found out on this topic but I am not skilled enough to understand this: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/520

This is how the views.py looks like:

```
def item_view(request,pk):
    pk_binairy = urlsafe_base64_decode(pk)
    pk_int = int.from_bytes(pk_binairy, byteorder='little')
    desired_url_forward_object = get_object_or_404(forwards,pk = pk_int)
    channel_cleaned_utm = re.sub(' +',' ',"".join([request.GET.get('utm_source', ''),' ',request.GET.get('utm_medium', ''),' ',request.GET.get('utm_campaign', ''),' ',request.GET.get('utm_term', ''),' ',request.GET.get('utm_content', '')]))
    channel_cleaned = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if channel_cleaned is None:
        channel_cleaned = 'Direct Traffic'
    visitor_ip_request = get_client_ip(request)
    location_request = get_client_location(request, visitor_ip_request)
    clickstat = clickstats(
        urlid = pk_int,
        user = desired_url_forward_object.user,
        channel = channel_cleaned,
        visitor_ip = visitor_ip_request,
        city = location_request['city'],
        region = location_request['region'],
        country = location_request['country'],
        device_type =  request.user_agent.device.family,
        browser = request.user_agent.browser.family,
        browser_version = request.user_agent.browser.version_string,
        operating_system = request.user_agent.os.family ,
        operating_system_version = request.user_agent.os.version_string
        )
    clickstat.save()

    if desired_url_forward_object.counterA <= desired_url_forward_object.counterB:
        desired_url_forward = desired_url_forward_object.urlA
        desired_url_forward_object.counterA = F('counterA') + 1
    else:
        desired_url_forward = desired_url_forward_object.urlB
        desired_url_forward_object.counterB = F('counterB') + 1
    desired_url_forward_object.save()
    return redirect(desired_url_forward)
```

Anyone suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you hosting this? Is this problem exhibited on the django dev server or are you using something like uwsgi+nginx?

Comment: I am hosting this on a heroku environment. I use Gunircorn and it runs on postgreSQL database. I disable the saving and if loop at the end. Minimised the lookups and hardcoded so it looks like a function, just redirecting to a different page, and it still is the same. same happen with this: `def forwardtest(request):
 return redirect('http://www.google.com')`

Comment: additionally, it now seems that the timeout is only raised when the redirect is activated on an android device. so when i use an iPad instead of android phone, the redirect causes no timeout issues. the computer doing the hosting doesn't give this issue either wen doing the redirection. so it looks like a chrome mobile issue?